# GET Request 200 to json

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, cloudflare

I am trying to send a fetch request to a URL to receive some JSON, all I get back is HTTP/1.1 200 OK, when I try to console.log my request, I don't see anything in the console, I am trying to console.log the request as JSON. I am using Cloudflare's wrangler tool for the project and coding it in javascript Here is my code:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest((event)))
})
/**
 * Respond with hello worker text
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
  return new Response('Hello worker!', {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  })
}
const url =`URL`;

const res="";

fetch(`MYURL`)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
   dataRecieved=JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(dataRecieved);
  });
```

Comment: Please check the networks tab for the response!

Comment: `'Hello worker!'` is not a valid JSON. What is the object you expect? It can be for example: `'{"message": "Hello worker!"}'`

Comment: The object I expect is the json from this url: ```https://cfw-takehome.developers.workers.dev/api/variants ```I am trying to console.log it but can't seem to do that with this code.

Answer (score 1):

`'Hello worker!'` is not a valid JSON so `JSON.parse(data)` will not be able to work properly. You should use a code like this to return a valid JSON in the response:

```
return new Response('{"variants":["your-private-url/variants/1","your-private-url/variants/2"]}', {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    status: 200
  })
```

Now to have the result as you mentioned in your comments you need to remove the event listener and handle the `fetch` call this way:

```
fetch('your-private-url')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    // 'data' here contains the object returned by your request.
    // So you can log the whole object received to see its content:
    console.log('Received data:\n', data);

    // And you can access the fields and log them:
    data.variants.forEach(variant => {
        console.log('Reveived variant: ', variant);
    });
  });
```

Comment: The object I expect is the json from this url: https://cfw-takehome.developers.workers.dev/api/variants I am trying to console.log it but can't seem to do that with this code

Comment: I updated the response content to return the object you expect. I've hidden the real url. So you will put `cfw-takehome..` instead of `your-private-url`

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to have the fetch request receive the variants from the url instead of me manually returning it in the ```handleRequest()``` function?

Comment: I have to retrieve the json from the link which is part of the test

Comment: Am not sure I understand what you want to achieve. You want to remove the `addEventListener`? Because in your current code you can access the json object received and get the variants like this: `dataRecieved.variants[0]` and `dataRecieved.variants[1]` (supposing you have 2 elements there)

Comment: The URL has JSON, I want to receive that json and save it to a variable. I also wanna console.log() the links in the json to the console

Comment: I updated my answer to show how the `fetch()` call should be to achieve what you asked for. `data` object already contains all what you need.